# Why did Peik Lin say, "I'm not an animal"?

Tags: plot-explanation, crazy-rich-asians

In Crazy Rich Asians (2018), before she eats dinner at Nick Young's grandmother's residence, Peik Lin picks a cocktail dress out of her car trunk:

> Rachel: You have a cocktail dress in your trunk?
>
> Peik: **I'm not an animal**, Rachel.

Why did Peik Lin say, "I'm not an animal"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Much of this movie is a caricature of the wildly-rich Singaporean lifestyle. Clothing and appearances are crucially important.  Therefore, Peik Lin is revealed to have a variety of outfits with her for multiple occasions -- it would be low class to attend a cocktail party in anything other than a cocktail dress.  When she bluntly says, "I'm not an animal, Rachel," she is implying that only an "animal" would wear the wrong type of outfit to such a sophisticated gathering. She could have said, "I wouldn't be caught dead wearing anything other than a cocktail dress to Nick Young's party," but she humorously exaggerated the point by saying that only the lowest type of person would make that unforgivable fashion mistake.

Comment: "Why are you wearing a tux?" "It's after six, what am I, a farmer?"

Comment: @MikeTheLiar Jack Donaghy on _30 Rock_!  Perfect!!